# How to use if and else in LATEX pseudo code

Tags: overleaf

How to use if else in Latex Pseudo code. Here is the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}  % Use Input in the format of Algorithm  
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}} % Use Output in the format of Algorithm  


\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[htb]
\caption{}
\label{alg:algorithm1}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \If{$R != Null$}
    \For{each $R_i\in R$}
    \State{Score(i) = Evaluation($R_i$)}
    \Else{111}
    %\State{$D_n$ = $R$}
    \EndIf\\
    \Return{$D_n$}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

I want to make the 'else' to be shown in the pseudo code. And it should have the same class as 'if'. Currently, what I get is just 111, not else 111. How to optimize it?

Comment: You need a \ElsIf{111}. You also have to insert the `\usepackage` statements before you use `\renewcommand`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in my comment, the correct code is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[htb]
\caption{}
\label{alg:algorithm1}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \If{$R \neq Null$}
        \For{each $R_i\in R$}
            \State{Score(i) = Evaluation($R_i$)}
        \EndFor
    \ElsIf{111}
        \State{$D_n$ = $R$}
    \EndIf
    \State{\Return{$D_n$}}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works